# Can I safely run a LED light bulb from a UPS?

Tags: power-supply, led, ups

I think I blew a capacitor (heard a pop sound) inside a UPS when I plugged in a 29 watt LED light bulb. It still works, but now the UPS is really slow to switch back to AC power after a brownout.

Model: Tripp Lite SMART750USB

Comment: Mate, is your question about UPS or USB?

Comment: The LED bulb still works when plugged into an AC outlet, right?

Comment: Yes, the LED light bulb still works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LED lamp probably has a switching power supply with a capacitor and bridge rectifier. This would account for a brief arc and pop when screwed in since the capacitor could draw many amperes if it makes contact near the peak of the AC line.

Since UPS units are designed to work with massive switching power supplies on PCs it seems unlikely that it would have damaged the UPS in any way.

Answer (score 0):

An LED lamp, or any lamp for that matter, shouldn't have any effect on the UPS itself.  The output is generally magnetically (transformer) isolated from the switching electronics of the UPS.

Are you absolutely certain you didn't short the output somehow when plugging your lamp in?

Comment: I don't see how I would short the output. I screwed the LED light bulb into a desk lamp that plugged into the UPS and immediately heard a pop sound so I replaced it with an incandescent light bulb.

Comment: The "inverter" in the UPS is a type of switching power supply, and unless it's a very expensive UPS, its output probably is pretty far from a sine wave.  The power supply in the LED "light bulb" also is a switching power supply.  Your Mileage May Vary if you feed the output of one switcher to the input of another switcher.